# C language strings : password and username validation

Tags: c, clang

I want to collect username and password with this format —> "username":"password"
which is requires

- **n** is number of the users input (how many time program will collect input)
- **username** has to be 4 characters and the first character won’t be a number (but second to the last character is alright) it has to contains the uppercase or lowercase letters.
- **password** can be 4-8 characters and it has to have at least 2 numbers init also it has to contains the uppercase and lowercase letters.

If username and password are valid the program will print out the validated username.

example
input

```
4
Std1: jEb20j //ps. I add the white space intentionally to tell that the white space isn’t matter.
cs1r:9i9J9T
a2Mn:cat88
User5:feb20E
```

output

```
Std1
cs1r
```

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void checking(char []);

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();
    
    char users[14];
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        gets(users);
        
        checking(users);
    }
}

void checking(char users[]) {
    int len = strlen(users);
    char num[10] = "0123456789";
    if(users[4] == ":") {
        //check username
        int i, checknum=0;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            checknum = 0;
            if(users[0] == num[i]) {
                checknum = 1;
            }
        }
        if(!checknum) {
            int checkul = 0;
            for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
                checkul = 0;
                if(users[i] >= 'A' && users[i] <= 'Z') {
                    if(users[i] >= 'a' && users[i] <= 'z') {
                        checkul = 1;
                    } else checkul = 0;
                } else checkul = 0;
            }
            //check password
            if(checkul) {
                int j,f = len-5;
                int numcheck = 0;
                if(f >= 4 && f <= 8) {
                    int check2 = 0;
                    for(i=5;i<f;i++) {
                        check2 = 0;
                        if(users[i] >= 'A' && users[i] <= 'Z') {
                            if(users[i] >= 'a' && users[i] <= 'Z') {
                                check2 = 1;
                            } else check2 = 0;
                        } else check2 = 0;
                        
                        if(check2) {
                            for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
                                if(num[j] == users[i]) {
                                    numcheck++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(numcheck >= 2) {
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
                        printf("%s\n" ,users[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t know if the error is caused by my input or the conditions. I can’t print out any output.

I want to print out like my example, thank you

Comment: Create individual functions - one for checking username, one for checking password.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: If this condition is true `users[i] >= 'A' && users[i] <= 'Z'` then the next condition `users[i] >= 'a' && users[i] <= 'z'` can never be true. Not sure what that logic is for but you should think about it a bit since `checkul` will always be 0. If you do fix the logic then consider that the value is reset on each iteration of the loop so only the last iteration matters. The `check2` loop has the same problem but also an additional typo.

Comment: recommend checking out [`isalpha`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) and friends instead of rolling your own checks.

Comment: @doeeyes, With `char users[14];  gets(users);`, what do you expect to happen with input more than 13 characters?

Answer (score 2):

You should modularize your code, split into functions, use available functions in the C library.

Few problems that I noticed in your code:

1. `users[4] == ":"` - you should check for `':'` instead of `":"`.
2. You are using `gets()` which is not recommended anymore, also C11 seems to have removed it. Use `fgets()` or `scanf` instead.

I was bored so I wrote the below code. You can use it for learning purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool check_username(const char* username)
{
    if (strlen(username) != 4)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (isdigit(username[0]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(username[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool check_password(const char* password)
{
    size_t len = strlen(password);
    if (len < 4 || len > 8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    unsigned int digit_count = 0;
    bool is_upper_case_present = false;
    bool is_lower_case_present = false;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(password[i]))
        {
            digit_count++;
        }
        if (isupper(password[i]))
        {
            is_upper_case_present = true;
        }
        if (islower(password[i]))
        {
            is_lower_case_present = true;
        }
    }
    if (digit_count < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!is_upper_case_present || !is_lower_case_present)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

const char* check_username_password(const char* username_password)
{
    // find : and break into two strings
    const char* occurence = strchr(username_password, ':');
    if (occurence == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t no_of_username_chars = (occurence - username_password) / sizeof(char);
    char* username = calloc(no_of_username_chars + 1, sizeof(char));
    char* u = username;
    for (char* p = (char*) username_password; p != occurence; p++)
    {
        *u = *p;
        u++;
    }
    //printf("DEBUG username=%s\n", username);
    if (!check_username(username))
    {
        free((void*) username);
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t no_of_password_chars = strlen(username_password) - ((occurence - username_password) / sizeof(char));
    char* password = calloc(no_of_password_chars, sizeof(char));
    char* q = password;
    for (char* p = (char*) occurence + 1; *p != NULL; p++)
    {
        if (!isspace(*p))
        {
            *q = *p;
            q++;
        }
    }
    //printf("DEBUG password=%s\n", password);
    if (!check_password(password))
    {
        free((void*) username);
        free((void*) password);
        return NULL;
    }
    free((void*) password);
    return username;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int no_of_users = 0;
    printf("Enter no. of users: ");
    scanf("%d", &no_of_users);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < no_of_users; i++)
    {
        char username_password[256] = {0};
        if (fgets(username_password, sizeof(username_password), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            perror("Something went wrong during read of input\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        const char* username = check_username_password(username_password);
        if (username != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", username);
            free((void*)username);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, thanks, made the changes.